# Why can I launch a desktop shortcut with the mouse, but not my touchscreen?

Tags: 20.04, shortcuts, touchscreen

I have made a `.desktop` file that works to launch a script I have written:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version = 1.0
Exec=/home/me/myscript.sh
Name=My Script
Commment="Run my script"
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Categories=Application
Icon=/home/me/Pictures/myicon.png
```

This puts my shortcut with the correct icon on the desktop. I selected "Allow Launching" from the right-click menu.  It works perfectly when I double click it with the mouse.

It is installed on a [SurfaceBook2](https://github.com/linux-surface/linux-surface), where the touchscreen is working (I can interact with the title bar, application buttons and the on-screen keyboard).  But I can't launch the shortcut by touch.  Single-tap, double-tap, hold: nothing works. The icon is highlighted when I touch it, but it never starts.

1. How do I make this shortcut launchable by touch?
2. Where is the documentation for how Ubuntu 20 handles`.desktop` files?